# LaTeX в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, latex

Можно ли вставить в TextView LaTeX-код так, чтобы при запуске приложения он отображался в виде формулы? 
Погуглив, я нашел плагин https://github.com/hsz/idea-latex , но как я понимаю, это не то, что мне надо.

Comment: Причем здесь Android Studio? Это только инструмент, то же самое вы будете делать, даже если будете писать свою программу в Блокноте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это просто плагин к IDEA, он реализует поддержку LaTeX в IDE(подсветка синтаксиса и ещё кое-что).
Вы можете использовать не TextView, а, например, WebView и MathJax, это кажется самый простой способ заполучить красивые LaTeX формулки в своём приложении :)